# Twitter Oauth login in a cron agent executing PHP file evenry 2 minutes

Tags: php, oauth, cron

I'm using Twitter Basic authentification in a CRON agent to get et savelist of tweets in SQL db of 5 of my twitter account. Because we have to use Oauth after June 30th I'm searching to know how can I use oauth without connecting me manually. In fact I don't have user interface in my PHP file executed every 2 minutes.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Joel.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.twitter.com/

Start by creating an application with Twitter, then if you go back to the Dev site you can find your own OAuth tokens (so you don't need to go through the whole process of authorizing your own account).

Then check out the PHP [libraries](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries) to write your script, I recommend you take a look at [twitteroauth](http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) as that's the most popular one.

Comment: Thx for your answer. But where can I get Oauth tokens? I didn't see it/them.

Joel.

Comment: thx for your help. But where and how can I get my own OAuth tokens? thx. you you say "go back to the dev site" which ones?
Regards,
Joel.

Comment: Log in to twitter then go back to the dev site - http://dev.twitter.com/ - it should recognise your logged in and you will see 'Your Apps' then click on 'Edit Details' then on the right click 'Application detail' then 'My Access Token'