# Twitter → how get user home timeline

Tags: php, twitter

How can i get user home timeline if I have his login & password?

Comment: The twitter API docs should give you all information that you need. Did you look at them?

Comment: Yes, I looked at them and i don't find there answer on my question.

Answer (score 2):

Using login + password is not recommended, you should let OAuth to give your webservice access.

There are [several libraries](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#php) for PHP + Twitter, which one are you planning to use?

Edit: you can use OAuth with crontab, just log in to twitter with the account in your browser and you'll be able to get the tokens from dev.twitter.com to use in your PHP. Check this thread for more detailed answer: [Twitter Oauth login in a cron agent executing PHP file evenry 2 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995363)

Comment: +1! Non-OAuth-authorization is deprecated and should be replaced immediately.

Comment: I use library from Abraham Williams and i don't have problems with OAuth in my application.

Comment: I just want to know — can i get user home time line without auth user in my application. By crontab for example.

Comment: @Nick Pavluk: You can use the public timeline.

Comment: @elusive: No, it's not that i want. I need to get specific user home timeline by crontab.

Comment: @Nick it shouldn't matter whether your script is run through cron or a web server, should it?

Comment: @Pekka: There is a difference. Using OAuth you can get user home_timeline only with auth one in a browser. You can't do it with cron. API method “statuses/home_timeline” doesn't have parameter «screen_name”

Comment: @dain: yes, You are right, but in that way you can get only your own home_timeline. I need third part user home_timelines.

Comment: @Nick you could ask for user OAuth tokens instead of username / password?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the public feed of a user timeline from a URL like this and parse it however you want

> http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=stephenfry

Comment: No, “user_timeline returns the 20 most recent statuses posted by the authenticating user” and i need “home_timeline” with wonderful argument «screen_name». But it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

One way i see → write letter to api@twitter.com and use xAuth with user login and password.